# jQuery Callback function for rotating object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, callback, rotation

I cannot figure out how to add callback function to this CSS animation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/H2g74/)

HTML

```
<button>Rotate</button><br><br>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("div").animate({textIndent: "-=90"}, 
          {step: function(now,fx)
           {$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)')},duration:'slow'},
       'linear')
    })
})
```

Comment: what kind of callback function do you want? btw, looks like you use  callback function for `step` in a uncessary way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H2g74/4/ 

find you callback, hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [complete option](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("div").animate({textIndent: "-=90"}, 
          {step: function(now,fx)
           {$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)')},duration:'slow',complete:function(){alert("hi");}},
       'linear')
    })
})
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H2g74/1/

Comment: we have many kinds of callback function, the callback for `complete` is just ***1 of those***. It's still unclear on what the OP wants.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I have to change IDs for wrapped group of divs that are being rotated together as one object, if that makes sense to you. The example I created was very simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css animation, and have a callback called with the same duration:

#### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var now = -90;
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("div").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+now+'deg)');
      now -= 90;
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    });
})

function callback() {
 alert('callback func');   
}
```

#### css

```
div {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color: grey;
     -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/EVdjx/